# When docked, Music Player starts playing when my AVPlayer pauses

Tags: ios, avplayer, avaudiosession

I am writing a music player. This problem occurs when the device is docked to my Car stereo.

Whether the built-in Music App is active or not, it launches and starts playing some random selection. If I start my App and play, all is well until I pause: as soon as I do that, the Music App muscles in again! This happens even if I kill the Music App.

Is there a way that my App can tell all other AudioApps (and especially Music) to butt out when my App is running, even when the player is paused?

Comment: This problem really is between you and your car.

Comment: What kind of audio session are you using?

Comment: [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];

Comment: On my car I have to set the car stereo to 'non-ipod' mode in its settings so this doesn't happen. When the battery on the car was disconnected I had to set this again as the default was for it to be in 'ipod' mode. When it's in ipod mode it sends an autoplay whenever it is turned on or whenever a track stops playing. As this is all happening on the car's side of things I don't think there's anything that will fix it from the iOS side.

Comment: I am wondering if I should play a loop of silence when my output route is a Dock Connector and my app has paused.